# How can I define a variable in the PHP header ('Location:)

Tags: php

I'm trying to redirect to another page when a record is added to the database.

I want to make sure that this instruction creates an address which contains the id number.

```
header('Location:inventory_issue_view.php?filterer_client_name=<%%URLVALUE(suiting_reference_no)%%>');
```

However the address I get from this is

```
inventory_issue_view.php?filterer_client_name=<%%URLVALUE(suiting_reference_no)%%>
```

I know the value of

```
<%%URLVALUE(suiting_reference_no)%%>
```

is correct since if I edit the instruction to this:

```
header('Location:inventory_issue_view.php?filterer_client_name=7499');
```

I get the correct address.

Using this code:

```
 $client=sqlValue("SELECT suiting_reference_no FROM client_suiting WHERE client_name =     '{$data['client_name']}'");
```

I get a null value for $client

Using this code:

```
$client=sprintf("SELECT suiting_reference_no FROM client_suiting WHERE client_name = '{$data['client_name']}'");

    $client=SELECT%20suiting_reference_no%20FROM%20client_suiting%20WHERE%20client_name%20=%20%277489%27
```

This part of a hook after insert in an APPGini generated script.
An associative array where the keys are field names and the values are the field data values that were inserted into the new record.
     * For this table, the array items are:
     *     `$data['issue_date'], $data['client_name'], $data['suiting_ref'], $data['inventory_item'], $data['inventory_qty'], $data['inventory_item_size'], $data['inventory_size_category'], $data['inventory_cost'], $data['inventory_value']`

Now that I look at it again an easy solution would be if $client= $data['suiting_ref'] or however one should compose it.
     *

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `$_GET["suiting_reference_number"]` instead? This `<%%URLVALUE()%%>` talk seems very un-PHP.

Comment: Use [variable interpolation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double). `<%%xyz%%>` is not PHPs syntax for that.

Comment: check for quotes; you got ', not " ; in single quotes variables are not processed;;

Comment: Are you mixing languages?

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the id of the client? From a query or a form? Hovewer, try:

```
header("Location:inventory_issue_view.php?filterer_client_name=$clientId");
```

where `$clientId` is a variable containing the number.

Comment: This works using the following code:$client=7499;
 header ("Location:inventory_issue_view.php?filterer_client_name=$client");
So now it's just a matter of defining $client

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
header("Location:inventory_issue_view.php?filterer_client_name=".$clientId.");
```

or

```
header("Location:inventory_issue_view.php?filterer_client_name=$clientId");
```